# Any side-effects using SqlParameterCollection.Clear Method?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I have this specific situation where I need to execute a stored procedure 3 times before I declare it failed. Why 3 times because to check if a job that was started earlier finished. I am going to ask a separate question for deciding if there is a better approach. But for now here is what I am doing.

```
    mysqlparametersArray
    do{
        reader = MyStaticExecuteReader(query,mysqlparametersArray)
        Read()
        if(field(1)==true){
          return field(2);
        }
        else{
          //wait 1 sec
         }

    }while(field(1)==false);

MyStaticExecuteReader(query,mysqlparametersArray)
{
     //declare command
    //loop through mysqlparametersArray and add it to command
    //ExecuteReader
    return reader
}
```

Now  this occasionally gave me this error:

> The SqlParameter is already contained by another
>   SqlParameterCollection.

After doing some search I got this workaround to Clear the parameters collection so I did this:

```
MyStaticExecuteReader(query,mysqlparametersArray)
{
     //declare command
    //loop through mysqlparametersArray and add it to command Parameters Collection
    //ExecuteReader
    command.Parameters.Clear()
    return reader
}
```

Now I am not getting that error.

**Question:** Is there any side-effect using .Clear() method above?

**Note:** Above is a sample pseudo code. I actually execute reader and create parameters collection in a separate method in DAL class which is used by others too.  So I am not sure if making a check if parameters collection is empty or not before adding any parameters is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from overhead or possibly breaking other code that is shared, there is no issue with clearing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I have not ran into any side effects when I have used this method.